# Creating view in Big Query using apps script | Error : API call to bigquery.tables.insert failed with error: Required parameter is missing (line 21

Tags: google-apps-script, view, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a view in Big query from an apps script  but my code is giving me this error:

***Error : API call to bigquery.tables.insert failed with error: Required parameter is missing (line 21...***

I am not sure where i am going wrong. Please help.

Note: I am creating views  using an app script because i have to copy views from one project to another project in big query but Transfer-service copy only tables not views. I have SQL query for all of my views but dont want to run all this SQLs manually in destination project.

Script:

```
function create_view() {
  var projectId='MyProjectId';
  var datasetId= 'MyDatasetName';
  var tableID='MyViewName';
  var table={
    view: {
      query:
      'My query here',
      useLegacySql: false
    },
  tableReference:{
    projectId: projectId,
    datasetId: datasetId,
    tableID: tableID,
  },

};
var queryResults = BigQuery.Tables.insert(table,projectId,datasetId);
  Logger.log(queryResults.status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The request you are issuing is correct, except for one little detail: the 'd' in `tableID` must be lowercase as in `tableId`.
Your final code would look like the following:

```js
function create_view() {
  var projectId = 'MyProjectId';
  var datasetId = 'MyDatasetName';
  var tableId = 'MyViewName';
  var table={
    view: {
      query:
      'My query here',
      useLegacySql: false
    },
    tableReference:{
      projectId: projectId,
      datasetId: datasetId,
      tableId: tableId,
    },
  };

  var queryResults = BigQuery.Tables.insert(table,projectId,datasetId);
  Logger.log(queryResults.status);
}
```